# Next.js middleware to connect mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am working on a Next.js project and I want to connect it with MongoDB using mongoose. I want to make a middleware to run the connect function inside so I don't have to call connect function in each file I am using a mongoose model in.

this is my connect file:

```js
// src/utils/connect.js

import mongoose from 'mongoose'


// getting the connection uri
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI

// checking if MONGO_URI is defined
if (!MONGO_URI) {
    throw new Error(
        'Please define the MONGO_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
    )
}


// maintaining a cached connection to prevent reconnection (connections growing exponentially during API Route usage)
let cached = global.mongoose

// restiing the connection if there was no cached connection
if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongoose = null
}

/**
 * mongodb connection
 */
export default async function connect() {

    // returning the cached connection if it exists
    if (cached) {
        return cached
    }

    cached = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
        bufferCommands: false,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })

    return cached
}
```

it will connect mongoose with my MongoDB database and caches the connection for future use.

this is one of my example API routes:

```js
// src/pages/api/test.js

import connect from '../../utils/connect'
import Test from '../../models/Test';

export default async function handler(req, res) {

    // connect
    await connect()

    const data = await Test.find({});

    res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe', data })
}
```

now what I want to do is to get rid of that `await connect()` function in all routes and instead make a middleware to run the connect. and also is it better do so or not?